# How do you change ttk.Radiobutton circle/diamond?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I had to use `ttk.Radiobutton` instead of `Radiobutton` as I wanted to move the text above the circle but since then the circle has changed to a diamond. (See image below)

I have tried turning the indicator off with
`cTheme = ttk.Style()`
`cTheme.configure("TRadiobutton", indicatoron=False)`
but this seems to do nothing.

I want to change the new radiobutton shape from a diamond back to a circle.. or make it so when the button is clicked it changes shape or colour as currently nothing changes to show the user it has been clicked. Has anyone got any ideas?

[image: Example of new and old Radiobutton]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `indicatoron` option is not supported by the ttk version of the Radiobutton. However, you can change the ttk theme to one that has a circle for radiobuttons (e.g. 'clam' or 'alt'):

```
cTheme.theme_use('clam')
```

[image: screenshot clam theme]

Note that the theme change needs to be done before you configure the "TRadiobutton" style.

Also, to get rid of the initial blueish color in the button, change its state (the default state is 'alternate') to get a normal unselected radiobutton:

```
radiobutton.state(["!alternate"])
```

[image: screenshot after state change]

**EDIT:** If keeping the default theme, it is possible to make the selection of the button more visible, for instance by changing the selected color to bright green:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.IntVar(root, 1)
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.map('TRadiobutton', indicatorcolor=[('selected', '#00FF00')])
r1 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, value=1, variable=var, text='1')
r2 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, value=2, variable=var, text='2')
r1.pack()
r2.pack()
```

[image: Screenshot]

The other alternative is to create your own indicator from pictures and overriding the 'Radiobutton.indicator' in the layout of 'TRadiobutton':

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
  
var = tk.IntVar(root, 1)

style = ttk.Style(root)

data_unselected = b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x10\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\x1f\xf3\xffa\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x10\x9b\x00\x00\x10\x9b\x01t\x89\x9cK\x00\x00\x00\x19tEXtSoftware\x00www.inkscape.org\x9b\xee<\x1a\x00\x00\x01_IDAT8\x8d\xa5SMk\xc2@\x10}[*\x8b\x0c\xac\xa5\x7f@<Yu\x93\xfaGzV\xfbqM\xfeOXr\xc8/\xb0\xbd\xfaKb\x03\xad7k\xcf\xa5`\x0cB,;\xbdD\xb1i\xacB\x1f\xcce\x98\xf7\xf6\xcdc\x16\xf8\'DE\xaf\x06`\xa8\x94\x1a\x08!\xae\x00\x80\x99_\x97\xcb\xe5\x18\xc0#\x80\xcd_\x02}"\x9a\xb4Z\xad\x0b\xcf\xf3\xea\x8e\xe30\x00L\xa7S\x11E\xd1z>\x9f\x7ffYv\x03 \xaer\xd3\x97R\xae\xc20\xdcXksf\xfeQ\xd6\xda\xdc\x18\x93K)3\x00\xee/\xdbD\xf4\x1e\x86\xe1\xa6L,\x971&\'\xa2\xb7b\xd5\x1d\x1e\xb4\xd6i\xd5\xcbUN\xba\xddn\n\xe0\x0e\x00\xce\x00\xa0\xd1h\x8c|\xdf\xaf\x0bQ\x95i)u!\xe0\xfb~])5\xda\t\x00hk\xad\xf9(\xbb\x80\xd6\x9a\x85\x10\xed}\x01f>\x99\x8fb\x96w\x02\xcc<K\x92\xe4\xb8\xff\x02I\x92\x08f\x9e\xed\xf7\xee{\xbd\xde\xc9!v:\x9d\x14\xc0\xed\xbe@\x8d\x88\x16\xc6\x98\xa3\x02A\x10\xe4D4\x07p^vv-\xa5\xcc\x8c1\xf9\xa1C\n\x82 \x97R\xae\x008[Ryo\x97\x88&\xcdf\xf3\xd2\xf3\xbc\xba\xeb\xba\x0c\x00q\x1c\x8b(\x8a\xd6\x8b\xc5\xe2\xa38\xe5\xe7C\x02(\xac\r\x94R\xc3\xedg\xb2\xd6\xbe\xa4i:\x06\xf0\x04\xe0\xeb\xd4\xb0O\xc27yq5\xbb\x9e?8\xa4\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
img_unselected = tk.PhotoImage("radiobutton_unselected", master=root, data=data_unselected)
data_selected = b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x10\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\x1f\xf3\xffa\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x10\x9b\x00\x00\x10\x9b\x01t\x89\x9cK\x00\x00\x00\x19tEXtSoftware\x00www.inkscape.org\x9b\xee<\x1a\x00\x00\x01\xcdIDAT8\x8d\xa5S\xc1n\xda@\x10}k5ZE+\xd9\xab\xfe\x00\xe2\x94\x02\x86\xe6\x0f\xe0\x07zN\xd4\xa6W\xff\x0ff\xe5\x83\xbf \xb5\x0f\xc8\xa4\xea\xd9\xbf\x00\xb5\xd4\xe6F\xe9\t\xa3\xaa\x80\x83"\x19k\xa7\x07\xb0E\x02\xe9\xa1\x1di/\xb3\xfb\xde\xbcy3\x0b\xfcg\xb0\x13\xb93\x00\xd7\xa6i^1\xc6\xde\x00\x00\x11}_\xaf\xd7\xb7\x00>\x01\xd8\xfe\x8d\xe0R\x08qW\xaf\xd7\xa5\xe38\xe7\xedv\x9b\x00`2\x990\xdf\xf7\x1f\xa7\xd3\xe9\xef\xcdf\xf3\x0e\xc0\xf8\x94\x9aK\xce\xf9\x83\xe7y[\xaduNDO\x8e\xd6:WJ\xe5\x9c\xf3\r\x80\xce\x91l!\xc4O\xcf\xf3\xb6%`>\x9f\xe7A\x10\x14A\x10\x14i\x9aVDJ\xa9\\\x08\xf1c\xdfj\x15\x1fm\xdb\xce\xca\xca\xc3\xe1\xb0\xb0,\x8b\x00\x10\x00\x92RR\x14EE\xa9\xa4\xd9lf\x00>Th\xcb\xb2\xbe\x0c\x06\x83\xa2\xac|\x08>$)\x95\xf4\xfb\xfd\xc24\xcd\xcf\x00`\xec9.l\xdb&\x00\x88\xe3\xd8X\xadVG\x06-\x97K\xc4ql\x00\x80m\xdb\xc4\x18\xbb8$ "\xda\x8d\x85\x9d\x9a\xec.\x0c\xc3(\x1fc\xaflG@D\xf7I\x920\x00\xe8\xf5zZJy\x04\x96R\xa2\xdb\xedj\x00H\x92\x84\x11\xd1\xfd\xe1\xfdM\xab\xd5\xaaL\x8c\xa2\xa8\x90R>\xe9\x7f4\x1amK\x13\x1b\x8dF\x06\xe0\xfd!\xc1\x99\x10b\xa6\x94\xaa\xc6\x95\xa6i\x1e\x86a\x11\x86a\xb1X,\xaa\xbc\xeb\xba\xb9\x10b\n\xe0\xd5s\x95o9\xe7\x1b\xa5T\xfe\xd2"\xb9\xae\x9bs\xce\x1f\x00\xb4K\xd0s\xc7:B\x88\xbbZ\xad\xf6\xdaq\x9c\xf3N\xa7C\x000\x1e\x8f\x99\xef\xfb\x8f\xb3\xd9\xec\xd7~\x95\xbf\xbeD\x80\xbd\xb4+\xd34\xaf\xcb\xcf\xa4\xb5\xfe\x96e\xd9-\x80\x00@q\x02\xf3\xef\xf1\x07\x84\xe6=}U\x13]\xb7\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
img_selected = tk.PhotoImage("radiobutton_selected", master=root, data=data_selected)

style.element_create('custom.indicator', 'image', "radiobutton_unselected",
                     ('selected', '!disabled', "radiobutton_selected"))
style.layout(
    'TRadiobutton',
    [('Radiobutton.padding',
      {'sticky': 'nswe',
       'children': [('custom.indicator', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
                    ('Radiobutton.focus',
                     {'side': 'left',
                      'sticky': '',
                      'children': [('Radiobutton.label', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]})]})])

r1 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, value=1, variable=var, text='1')
r2 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, value=2, variable=var, text='2')
r1.pack()
r2.pack()
```

[image: screenshot]

Note that you will need extra images when defining the theme element if you want to have a noticeable "disabled" state.

Comment: I already have a custom theme in place so when I change to the "clam" theme it changes everything about my application. Do you know where I could find how to edit the theme on radiobuttons. I have found how to change the positioning and label location on them but nothing on the indicator colour/shape....?

Thanks, Jacob

Comment: @Jacob The only way to change the shape of the radiobutton (without changing theme) is to customize the TRadiobutton layout, replacing the indicator by a custom theme element made of images.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @Jacob you are welcome. I have added the code corresponding to my previous comment.